How to get multiple levels of test parameterization in googletest?
I've created an interface in C++.
class MyInterface {
public:
  virtual int doStuff(int i) = 0;
};

And a test suite for any implementations of this interface. There is a section in the googletest documentation that talks about this.
using Factory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface>();

class MyInterfaceTest : public testing::TestWithParam<Factory> {};

TEST_P(MyInterfaceTest, DoesStuff) {
  EXPECT_EQ(GetParam()()->doStuff(5), 25);
}

I'd also like to parameterize some arguments to the factory and have the basic tests use a set of values for all implementations.
using Factory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<MyInterface>(bool, int);

class MyInterfaceTest : public testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<Factory, std::tuple<bool, int>> {};

TEST_P(MyInterfaceTest, DoesStuff) {
  EXPECT_EQ(std::apply(std::get<0>(GetParam()), std::get<1>(GetParam())->doStuff(5), 25);
}

auto makeParams(Factory factory) {
  return testing::Combine(testing::Values(factory), testing::Bool(), testing::Values(0, 1, 65109));
}

This is ok since I can call it like so:
class MyImplementation : public MyInterface {
public:
  MyImplementation(bool frambulate, int cores);

  int doStuff(int i) override;
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(MyImplementationTest, MyInterfaceTest, 
 makeParams([](bool frambulate, int cores) { 
  return std::make_shared<MyImplementation>(frambulate, cores);
});

But it would be better if I could just pass my factory in and the "abstract tests" could somehow generate the test params.
But then it gets worse. Each implementation has its own parameters and I'd like to generate tests for a bunch of values for those. I don't know how to do this with parameterized tests.
I have something like this:
// In the base library:
struct TestCase {
  void run(Factory factory, bool frambulate, int cores);
};

std::vector<TestCase> tests = {Test1{}, Test2{}};

void runTestBattery(Factory factory) {
  for (auto frambulate : {true, false}) {
    for (auto cores : {0, 1, 65109}) {
      for (auto test : tests) {
        test.run(factory, frambulate, cores);
      }
    }
  }
};

// Then in the implementation's tests:
TEST(MyImplementationTest, RunTestBattery) {
  for (auto cache : {true, false}) {
    for (auto indexSize : {0, 1, 55}) {
      runTestBattery([&](bool frambulate, int cores) {
        return std::make_shared<MyImplementation>(frambulate, cores, cache, indexSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

This is far from ideal because it runs a lot of tests and if one of them fails it's hard to debug.
I'd like to turn this into parameterized tests but I don't know how.
